# The image of a segment is not dense into a square

Tags: general-topology

Let $f\colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ a continuous injection such that
$$
f(0,0)=(0,0), f(1,0)=(0,1), f(1,1)=(0,2), f(0,1)=(0,3).
$$
Let $S$ be the closed segment joining $(0,0)$ and $(0,3)$.

Prove that $f^{-1}[S]$ is not dense in $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I may be off, but since $f$ is continuous and $S$ is closed, then one must have that  $f^{-1}(S)$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]^2$, Therefore, if it were dense then it would be equal to $[0,1]^2$ -- can you prove this is not possible? (in particular, you would have $f([0,1]^2)=S$.

Comment: I agree, thanks Clement and Amitai; trying to generalize to higher dimensions, is it possible to prove on the same line of reasoning that a compact subset of $\mathbf{R}^3$ is not homeomorphic to a closed square in the plane $x=0$ of $\mathbf{R}^3$?

Comment: @jordan You should rephrase your last question, since what you wish to prove is false.

Comment: Right, I forgot to add "with non-empty interior"; let us say, the cube in $\mathbf{R}^3$ is not homemorphic to a closed square in $\mathbf{R}^3$..

Comment: Yes, it is possible to prove that. The only ways I know of doing so involve either homotopy groups of homology groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Clement, if $f^{-1}(S)$ were dense in $[0,1]^2$, it would mean that the image of $f$ is $S$. Since $f$ is continuous and injective, from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, we would actually get that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Now we just need to prove that the square is not homeomorphic to a segment. For every point $p\in[0,1]^2$, the space $[0,1]^2\setminus \{p\}$ is connected. This is not the case with the segment.